# Function Notations

Tags: functions, notation

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and let $x\in X$. For the image of $x$ under $f$, a popular notation is $f(x)$; while some author prefers $(x)f$. To me, $(x)f$ is far more natural as if we apply a function $f$, then $g$, the result is naturally $f\circ g$ since $$((x)f)g=(x)(f\circ g).$$ But if we use the "usual" one, $f\circ g$ means applying $g$ first, followed by $f$; the order is "reversed".

My question is: **Is the notation $(x)f$ outdated, or perhaps "dead"? If one write a research paper/thesis, is it still considered acceptable if s/he uses the notation $(x)f$ instead of $f(x)$?**

By the way, under this notation many well known functions will look a bit weird; for example, are you comfortable with $\pi\sin=0$?

Comment: Yeah, composition does make more sense this way, if it were up to me, I would start using this notation. However, I've never seen it anywhere, until now.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for $\circ$ being more natural like that. Is it because we read from left to right? Not all of us do...

Comment: @AmitaiYuval, I have seen it in several textbooks, one of them is Lie Algebras by Nathan Jacobson. But it was written in 1961; so that's why I ask if this notation is "dead" now.

Comment: @GitGud, I mean at least for English (or German or French or Chinese or Japanese, etc) speakers. Of course if one is more comfortable with Arabic or Hebrew the picture will be completely different.